# Running cshell command from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, csh

I create a Java class in Eclipse. In this class, I want to call a CShell command and get the Console output to check the result.

To run this command, I have to source lic.cshrc file to define some immediate environment (will be removed when the command complete)

Content of lic.cshrc

```
setenv CSD_HOME /soft/soft/I-2013.12-SP2-2
set path = ( $CSD_HOME/bin $path )
if ( $?LM_LICENSE_FILE ) then
    setenv LM_LICENSE_FILE /soft/licenses/clientlic/lic:27000:$LM_LICENSE_FILE
else
    setenv LM_LICENSE_FILE /soft/licenses/clientlic/lic:27000
endif
```

Command to run

```
source lic.cshrc
importData ......
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: One of the Runtime.exec() variants.

Comment: Use this link to know more. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: so you can't make a wrapper script that contains both the `source` and `importData ...` command? (That is a quick solution). Good luck.